# For Loop and If statement not Looping correctly in web scraping

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

This is supposed to scrape the given site until the link is uploaded to the website and then email me the info, this all works fine if I enter in keywords of links already on the website, but if the keywords I give aren't on the website, a random link is emailed to me. How can I loop this so that the script scrapes until the link with the given 3 keywords is found- and then proceed with the rest of the script.. Please, loop this in any way you can figure! (I have omitted email info)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import urllib2
import time
from lxml import etree
while True:
    keyword1 = "spam"
    keyword2 = "notonwebsite"
    keyword3 = "stackoverflow"
    print("starting")
    r = requests.get('http://kithnyc.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=60594372&to=9545825095')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('loc')
    for link in links:
        if keyword1 in link.text and keyword2 in link.text and keyword3 in link.text:
            logic = True
        if logic == True:
            continue

    print(link.text)
    jake = str(link.text)
```

Comment: You got a problem with control flow. The rest of the code will run whether the keywords are there or not. Put the rest of the code where break statement is. And put break on the last line.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi could you please write this? when I do this it runs through the script once and ends not printing anything but "starting"...

Comment: @martianwars any suggestions?

Comment: Please reduce your code if you can and provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Sure thing, I've been playing with it, please attempt to loop this until first if statement is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. I changed it so the code is more clear. I think it should work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import urllib2
import time
from lxml import etree
while True:
    keyword1 = "spam"
    keyword2 = "notonwebsite"
    keyword3 = "stackoverflow"
    print("starting")
    r = requests.get('http://kithnyc.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=60594372&to=9545825095')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('loc')
    for link in links:
        while (keyword1 in link.text and keyword2 in link.text and keyword3 in link.text):
            print(link.text)
            jake = str(link.text)
```